How to package file add in Home file page JS
Hi Everyone My Question is How to add Package jS file add in home page means agar user koi package buy krey toh us package main user ko benefit diye gey hai wo mil jaye or koi doosre na mile or jo jo wo kaam kren wo home page main jo div add kiye hai un main add ho jaye
I don't No because i'm a new coder so please help
